# Problem with the layouts in making a JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Here is a screenshot of my `JFrame`.  This will be the main window to my application.

[image]

So the problem is that all the buttons are inline with each other, whereas I want them to be one under the other i.e. `Add Contact` under `Show Contacts`.

So how can I do that?

Here is my code for the `JFrame`.

```
public class CRUDFrame extends JFrame {
    public CRUDFrame(){
        super("AppCRUD");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button1, button2, button3, button4;

        button1 = new JButton(" Show Contacts ");
        button2 = new JButton(" Add Contact ");
        button3 = new JButton(" Update Number in a Contact ");
        button4 = new JButton(" Delete a Contact ");
        add(button1);       
        add(button2);  
        add(button3); 
        add(button4);
    }
}
`
```

Comment: I think the answer lies in the LayoutManagers. but i can't understand them at all. If there is a **really** good tutorial that you may know of, please post link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been some good answers centered around 'use a layout'.  This example espouses the same advice, but also introduces the concept of nesting one layout within another. E.G. the `JPanel` containing the `JButton`s has a `GridLayout`.  That panel is placed in the `NORTH` of a panel that is then added to the `WEST` of the main 'gui' panel.

The other components are added in order to show how the column of buttons *might* go together with other components in the main user interface.

#### Contact.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class Contact {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                gui.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(3,3,3,3) );

                JPanel controls = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5,5) );

                JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,4,4));
                buttons.add( new JButton("Show") );
                buttons.add( new JButton("Add") );
                buttons.add( new JButton("Update Number") );
                buttons.add( new JButton("Delete") );
                buttons.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Contact") );

                controls.add( buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH );

                controls.add(new JScrollPane(new JTree()), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                gui.add(controls, BorderLayout.WEST);

                gui.add(new JTextArea("CardLayout for CRUD components.",10,30));

                gui.add(new JLabel("Output label.."), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
                toolbar.add(new JCheckBox("Auto save", true));
                toolbar.add(new JCheckBox("Always On Top"));
                gui.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: BTW - If you found that useful, you might also be interested in this other [example of a nested layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271).  It allows the PLAF to be changed at run-time, and demonstrates dynamic addition of `JLabel` instances.

Comment: Why did you use `JPanel` instead of `JFrame`?

Comment: A `JPanel` can be put into a `JFrame`, or a `JApplet`, or a `JOptionPane`, or a `JInternalFrame`, or in a layout constraint within another `JPanel`, or..  It is all about choice, and leaving the options wide open.  As to why I put the `JPanel` into a `JOptionPane` rather than a `JFrame` in that code, it comes down to the `JOptionPane` requiring less lines of code.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use box layout and set dimension for each button. Check the below link.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: +1 good answer to the problem. Other alternatives standard Java are: GridLayout, GridBagLayout. Non-standard: TableLayout will help for sure, and I think that also MiGLayout might do the trick.

Comment: I'll realy prefer the standard `GridLayout`, because it will automatically **adjust** the size of each component to match them. This is better than manually setting the dimensions of each button.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html which discusses the various layout managers that Swing offers. GridBagLayout is probably what you need.